# Changing forgotten root password MySQL 5.7.4

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, root, windows-server-2012, reset-password

As title states I'm trying to change a forgotten MySQL root password. I followed the instructions detailed by Omar Bourja [here](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79027) (running the MySQL server with the `--skip-grant-tables` option & then using `update mysql.user set authentication_string=password('MyNewPass') where user='root';`).

But while the action output shows that change went through (`1 row(s) affected Rows matched: 1 Changed: 1 Warnings: 0`), I'm still not able to login as root with the new password.

I'm working in MySQL Workbench on Windows Server 2012. It should maybe also be noted that under services the MySQL57 service status is 'stopped' but mysqld is running as a process.

This is all still very new to me so please keep that in mind. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried the [official reset instructions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html)?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that first but it just remained stuck on "starting as process 7792 ...." & in the event viewer it showed an error "1131 You are using MySQL as an anonymous user and anonymous users are not allowed to change passwords." which is what lead me to the other method

Comment: Not sure what I did differently but I went through all the steps once more and this time it worked. (I guess I used `UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root';` instead of `update mysql.user set authentication_string=password('MyNewPass') where user='root';` even though I could swear I also tried that at some point.)

Answer (score 1):

After updating the password you should run this command line :

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

This will enable your updates on mysql.user table and you should be good to go.

More information can be found here [Mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/flush.html)

Comment: I did that but still I'm getting "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Comment: No sure what I did differently but I went through all the steps once more and this time it worked. (I guess I used `UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root';` instead of `update mysql.user set authentication_string=password('MyNewPass') where user='root'; ` even though I could swear I also tried that at some point.)